# Using javascript how can I set the value of Yes/No field column

Tags: column

I want to set the value of yes/no field.Through JavaScript I got the field control but unable to set value.

Comment: Monica, can you please paste the code you have for getting the field control?

Answer (score 2):

Yes/No control is a html checkbox so if you want to check it you need to set CHECKED attribute of the control to some value CHECKED = "checked" if you want to uncheck it you need to remove this attribute. To set value of the control you need to set "value" attribute to your value.

Easily done using jQuery:

```
$('input[name=SimpleHTMLCheckbox]').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `checked` the property using jQuery.

```
$('input[name=SimpleHTMLCheckbox]').prop('checked', true);
```